# One click to open development environment; activate "System Events" only if not already activated

Tags: console, applescript

I am using applescript to open my development environment.

UPDATE - This script works. I moved opening textmate to the end of the script and it works much more consistently now.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd web_sites/mydomain" in front window
    do script "rvm 1.9.2" in front window
    do script "rails server" in front window
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    if not (exists process "System Events") then
        tell application "System Events" to activate
    end if
    tell process "Terminal" to (keystroke "t" using command down)
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd web_sites/mydomain/public/stylesheets" in front window --> tab 2
    do script "rvm 1.9.2" in front window --> tab 2
    do script "sass --watch stylin.scss:stylin.css" in front window --> tab 2
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal" to (keystroke "t" using command down)
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd web_sites/mydomain" in front window --> tab 3
    do script "rvm 1.9.2" in front window --> tab 3
    do script "mate ." in front window

    delay 4
    do shell script "open -a Firefox http://localhost:3000"
end tell
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing three possible issues:

1. The `tell application "System Events"` lines are nested within the `tell` block addressing `Terminal`. You should create two `tell application "Terminal"` blocks with the `tell application "System Events"` lines in between them.
2. AppleScript cannot perform two actions on a single line. In other words, changing both occurrences of...

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to (keystroke "t" using command down) activate
   ```

   ...to this *block*...

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
      activate
      tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
   end tell
   ```

   ...should do the trick.
3. This isn't really an issue, but it isn't really necessary to activate `System Events` twice. The application has a default five minute quit delay (`System Events` will automatically quit after five minutes of inactivity). You should remove the second `activate` command provided your computer is fast.

Hopefully all this should make sense. :)

Comment: i updated the post to reflect what i understood you to be saying. The second part of the script is not working yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 52 it works now. i was able to create the conditional statement needed. Thanks.